# CMake Error: Could NOT find CryptoPP during Artery installation

Tags: c++, cmake, crypto++

I'm looking for solution to resolve the problems below. The error messages are generated during Vanetza installation of Artery ITS-G5 V2X system on Window OS.

Platform and tools are:

- Window 10
- MinGw-7.3.0
- CMake-3.13.0-rc1
- Boost 1.68
- Crypto++ -7.0.0

The error message:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find CryptoPP (missing: CryptoPP_INCLUDE_DIR CryptoPP_LIBRARY)
  (Required is at least version "5.6.1")

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/FindCryptoPP.cmake:11 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:77 (find_package)
```

Though I have searched much information related, I could not find the proper solution.

I need your help. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: If Artery wrote their CMake file around the time of Crypto++ 5.6.1, then it predates the one Crypto++ provided by several years. Where did you get your CMake file for Crypto++? The library supplies one as an unofficial add-on and it is located at [cryptopp-cmake](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-cmake). There's a version [tagged with 7.0.0](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-cmake/releases). Though it is unofficial it is well supported. Kitware helps with the CMake details, and we keep it up to date with our source files and flags.

Comment: Actually, I'm building the vanetza project located at https://github.com/riebl/vanetza, where CMake file is provided to build. Do I have to do something like path description on CMake file in order to the aforementioned problem?